# What is a good strategy for accessing an API which is limited to a static IP Address from Heroku?

Tags: http, heroku, nginx, amazon-ec2, ip-address

I need my app to be able access an third party API who limits access based on a single, static IP Address.

Due to the dynamic nature of the Heroku dynos and routing mesh, this is not possible - I'll need something with a fixed IP Address to act as a proxy.

An US East EC2 Linux/Nginx instance would seem the sensible choice, but these seems like a lot of work/maintenance for something pretty trivial. Does anyone know of any services out there that do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so after a bit of research I've discovered the best way to do this currently is indeed with an AWS US East EC2 instance running some sort of proxy. I've gone with linux/nginx.

I've also learned there is a Heroku add-on currently in alpha stage of development that will handle exactly this requirement. If you'd like to test it, get in touch with Heroku support.

Comment: Did you find a third party service that is production ready? (not an add on)

Comment: I didn't. Which really surprised me. There's thousands of proxy providers but mainly aimed at the private browsing market. Definitely a growing gap in the market for a service like this.

I guess this is newish requirement with the rise of platforms like Heroku leaving more traditional web service providers behind. I'll keep looking and if I come across something i'll update this post.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Proximo add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/proximo) to get a static outbound IP address via proxy without any of the maintenance headaches.

Comment: Proximo is nice. I also used [QuotaGuard Static](https://addons.heroku.com/quotaguardstatic) on another project. Both nice addons. They do the job.